# How do you compare a row in sql to the previous row?

Tags: sql, presto

I have two rows of data, and would like to compare one row to itself before, for e.g.

```
x1, id1
y1, id2
z1, id3
z1a, id3
```

I'd like to add a third column comparing ID3 to ID2 so I can right a conditional to give me a list of 0's and 1's, like this

```
x1, id1, 0
x2, id1, 1
x3, id2, 0
x4, id3, 0
x5, id3, 1
```

Is there anyway to do this????

Comment: please tag the RDBMS you're using. thanks

Comment: there are analytics functions , like **lag**

Comment: in case you're using SQL Server, have a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: You could use inner join like in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890411/comparing-sql-table-to-itself-self-join